# why does SP use unmanaged code?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, architecture, iis7

Or more specifically, where is that code coming from?  I guess it's not from the components built on top of web forms?  Is it the IIS integration?  Anyone have a (link) meaningful - (not marketecture) diagram describing this?  SP really seems like a collision of so many different MS technologies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> It may come as a surprise to you (which only shows how little it has
>   been written about this) but most of the ‘important’ things in
>   SharePoint are actually done through unmanaged code and the SharePoint
>   .NET object model provided by the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll is a sort
>   of a wrapper to this unmanaged world. Understanding how your code does
>   what you want it to do can be very helpful when troubleshooting
>   issues, fixing bugs, doing performance tuning and writing solid code
>   in general so I believe that every SharePoint developer should know
>   about SPRequest.
>
> As you are aware the gateway to doing anything in SharePoint is the
>   SPSite object. In order to get to any other objects that reside in a
>   site collection such as SPWeb, SPList, SPListItem, SPFile and others
>   we first need to obtain an SPSite and there is a very good reason for
>   that. Every SPSite instance holds a reference to the unmanaged WSS
>   world in the means of a field member of type SPRequest which is called
>   m_Request. The internal SPRequest class has an unmanaged reference to
>   a COM object called SP.SPRequest and having a ClassID of
>   BDEADEE2-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F which is implemented in and
>   exposed by the OWSSVR.DLL class library.
>
> The SP.SPRequest COM object exposes almost 400 basic operations and
>   almost everything you do with the Microsoft.NET managed SharePoint
>   object model that reads from or writes to the ContentDatabase
>   (including data, fields, content types, list schemas, etc) will
>   actually go via this unmanaged COM object.

For more info read [Hristo Pavlo's post](http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2009/01/19/understanding-sharepoint-sprequest/)